# GLUT library available on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to locate an Android-ready version of the OpenGL Glut library. Does anyone have a pointer?

Comment: Why do you want to use GLUT on Android? You know that GLUT never was meant for real-world applications, just for small demos and tutorials?

Comment: No I didn't know that; I was just looking at some demos and tutorials and wanted to try to run them... Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't ship with Glut (it is not Open Source), but there are some free alternatives and (simple) libs for Android.

Here is one example: http://code.google.com/p/akjava-android-project/

Answer (score 3):

`Glut` for `Android` exists and grows: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/android.php